# Terminal IDE: How to get a javascript to run?

Tags: javascript, terminal-ide

I've been playing around with Terminal IDE (I've recently discovered it) and I wish to run a javascript code I've written but when I issue to command to run according to Spartacus Rex's instructions, I always get a 'Permission Denied' message.  His command to run a script is: ./script_name.js

Spartacus gives examples in his help document with regards to running scripts he has written that come with this app of his (these scripts have a .sh extension).  When running them according to the ./script_name.sh command, all works fine.

Again, this is not working for me as I try to run my own scripts from the Terminal IDE command line.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I am a novice at all this programming, but I can figure out a lot on my own if pointed in the right direction at least.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not JavaScript Files you've been running with `./scriptName.sh` , actually those are bash shell scripts, Google for it to know what these files actually are. When you create a custom shell script, do not forget to add execution permission to it : `chmod +x your_custom_script.sh`. I don't think you can actually run `JavaScript` files inside Terminal IDE

> Not sure about `links` browser provided with it though